# My Login Form is showing even when I am already authenticated using React Routing?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-router, redux-saga

I am using redux saga in my app, I have a login form and when I get authenticated I use the Redirect Component to move to the app, I do this of course after changing my `connectedUser` state, that is like that :

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  user: {},
  status: ""
};
```

When authenticating my state change to `status:"AUTH"` and `user: { // user data }`, And this is how I redirect to the Application component and this is how my Authentication component rendering method looks like :

```
render() {

    if (this.props.connectedUser.status === "AUTH") {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }

    return MyLoginForm
}
```

My routes are defined in the whole app container :

```
function App(props) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <I18nProvider locale={props.language.language}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Application}></Route>
            <Route path="/authenticate" component={Authentification}></Route>
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </I18nProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

const msp = state => ({ language: state.language });

export default connect(msp, null)(App);
```

This is working fine, the disconnect button is doing fine too, but the problem occurs when I am redirected to my app ( meaning this route "/" ).

I want that when I refresh the page, I don't get redirected to the authentication page, Why I am going there ? it is obvious that my state is the initial state again, the status is "" again.

I am not asking for code but an idea, how to implement this.

I was trying to put that status in my localStorage but I don't feel like it is a good practise, also I found a problem whith this because If I change the localStorage then I will have to re render the component so the condition can be verified.

Answer (score 1):

```
I want that when I refresh the page, I don't get redirected to the authentification page, Why I am going there ? it is obvious that my state is the initial state again, the satus is "" again.
```

Sure! Refresh page will initial state again.

First of all, you need store current authentification after signed in. I suggest you use the [redux-sessionstorage](https://github.com/ilyagelman/redux-sessionstorage#readme)

Next, in Authentication component you should dispatch an action to get current authentification and update status in your state.